# Base64 Encoding takes too long time in Android

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm capturing an Image with the Camera. I save the File in the public photo directory and save the `Uri` to that file.

I want to save the Image in a `Base64` `String` and put it on a `HashMap` to put it then in a XML file later.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath,options);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
        int imgHeight = image.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = image.getWidth();
        while(imgHeight>2000){
            imgHeight = imgHeight / 2;
        }
        while(imgWidth>2000){
            imgWidth = imgWidth / 2;
        }

        Bitmap test = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,imgWidth,imgHeight,false);

        String stest = base64EncodeDecode.encodeToBase64(test);


        items.put("image",base64EncodeDecode.encodeToBase64(test);
        return null;
}
```

The `Base64` takes too long to encode it.
**encodeToBase64** Method

```
public String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Can you tell me if I do something wrong while encoding?

I hope my problem is clear.

Kind Regards!

Comment: How long is "too long" and how large is the byte array? How have you diagnosed that it's the base64 encoding that is taking the time rather than (say) the compression?

Comment: Why you are encode multiple times `String stest = base64EncodeDecode.encodeToBase64(test);
taskItems.put("image",base64EncodeDecode.encodeToBase64(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options)));` The first encoding string is for the bitmap for which you have done sampling. After sampling you want to encode the real bitmap?

Comment: yeah i saw it and so i edited the code! Thanks for the advice. I dont know why but the encoding takes a long time while debugging. On running it's "normal". Means you dont notice any encoding. What I get now is `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` when I pass the data into other `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` error is probably because you are passing to much data to the other `Activity`, there is a limit of how much you can send. Try compressing your image to 50% or 30% `image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);`